# spring Hibernate session time out

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc, hibernate-tools

I'm using Spring Hibernate template apache tomcat and MySQL. Everything works great in development, but when I deploy the app to a test server and let it run (largely idle) overnight, I'm usually greeted with this in the morning:

Following is my spring servlet.xml：

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" >
      <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000"/>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

How can i configure the spring servlet.xml to avoid this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: did you just say you're using apache tomcat 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

you can use hibernate properties to set pool of sessions and can also configure timeout.

`<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>`.

hope this will help you.

Comment: for more details see this : https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=279&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=&sid=7985f21867f3065736f9ee239f84c6c6

Comment: ok thank you...but where i can include this code inside my spring-servlet??. iam using hibernate template of spring frame-work,...

Answer (score 1):

Hi @jans it is said we should not use hibernate built-in connection poolin production. You can use C3p0 for connection pooling to avoid the error.
Also from something I learned just make sure you are closing all the sessions you used.
You can add below code in your "hibernateProperties" property.

```
<prop key= "hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>      
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
```

Comment: C3P0 comes with hibernate or you can add in your pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the SQL logs. The session has timed-out because some queries are taking too long than the default Transaction timeout.

Giving it a larger value won't resolve your problem. So, you need to configure a tool like [jdbcdslog](http://code.google.com/p/jdbcdslog/) to intercept all your queries and log the slow ones.

This way you can know for sure what's taking so long. It can be one inefficient query or a lot of small ones (N + 1 select) which would be better optimized with a join instead.

This way you can also figure out which queries need more indexes.

Alternatively, you can plan on setting up a second level query cache to speed-up some sloq queries which seldom change.